# how to fix Bitcoin core 14.2 on Windows 10 Home 64bit ver.

Tags: bitcoin-core

I cant install Bitcoin Core 13.2 thru 15.01 64 bit on my window 10 64 bit system it worked ver 14.2 worked before I tried to sign into coinbase that emailed me an address that needed to Identify my computer by clicking it. I clicked it to complete the authentication process. I had a problem with coinbase in the past and they closed my account when I tried to open another account they refused and closed my account again and sent me a message to close my account by clicking the box. since then I've been unable to open my bitcoin core wallet ver 14.2 I keep get this message[image][image]
and the this when I hit OK 
 I've tryed installing versions 13.0 thru 15.1 64bit then 32bit and alway the same thing when I click this OK the wallet shuts down!
I even went as far as installing Bitcoincore for Linux Mint 18.2 and it works great! BUT! I cant retrieve my Backed up wallet and coins from the windows wallet.dat. I'm at my wits end is there a Dev out their or on this site that can help me install Bitcore Core 14.2 (where I had my coins stored) on my Windows 10 Home PC?

Comment: What does Coinbase have anything to do with it?

Comment: The wallet was working fine until I connected it to coinbase via the identify computer button in a  email from them thats n the problems started. Then they closed my account because I didnt authorize a purchase of bitcoin and I was hacked.I think they bombed my computer with a virus

Comment: There is no relationship between Coinbase and Bitcoin Core.  There is no such thing as connecting Bitcoin Core to a Coinbase account.  How did you obtain Bitcoin Core?  I'm starting to suspect you downloaded a version prepackaged with malware.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say:

> I even went as far as installing Bitcoincore for Linux Mint 18.2 and it works great...

; you should just be able to just exit Bitcoin Core on both PC's and transfer your `wallet.dat` from the Windows PC to the `~/.bitcoin` folder on your Linux PC, assuming all are default data directory and wallet file name.

Answer (score 0):

first method (if the 2nd method completely wont work):
Go the C:\Users\%USERNAME&\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\blocks

(no need to edit the username part)

and then delete everything in it

OR

second method (recommended and faster):
Start the bitcoin core using -rebuild or -reindex flag

Comment: cant get into The wallet to start a rebuild tried the reindex from the cmd prompt that doest work either

Comment: You can backup the wallet and delete everything in the data directory

Comment: There is no "-rebuild" option in Bitcoin Core.